# Why can't I access SQL Server remotely?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am currently running a named instance of SQL server 2014 on a windows server 2012 environment. From what I've gathered from Google I think I've configured the firewall settings correctly but for some reason I still can't connect to my database. I am sure that it is a firewall issue as I've tested my connection with the firewall switched off on the server and I seem to be able to connect just fine.

On my server I have allowed UDP on port 1434 and and TCP on 1435. I have configured the named instance of SQL server to user port 1435

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: Not sure if it matters but the default instance is running on 1433 and I can access that just fine

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: Just to double check, can you right click your server, open up "Server Properties" click "Connections" and verify that "Allow remote connections" is checked?

Comment: Find `SQL Server Configuration Manager` run it.  Go to SQL Server Services and on the right side run SQL Server Browser if it is stopped.

Comment: SQL Server browser is definitely running and Allow Remote Connections is checked. Like I said, I can access the database remotely if I switch my firewall off